# Topic: Atwood's Machine. Can someone please explain to me how the coordinates are assigned in this question? (Competitive physics by Ricardo)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

[image]

Where did 0 come in the first string?
Also, I just wanted to know if my understanding is correct when it comes to identifying the strings... I highlighted the ones that I believe are the sets of inextensible strings acting.
[image]

Comment: The last sentence just before the problem begins - all the lengths are set to $0$ since their derivatives cannot contribute. I find it weird ($l = 0$ is quite amusing), but the idea is to make the calculations less congested, I guess. In reality, of course, if the length of the string is $l$, then the coordinate is $l-x$.

Comment: The way the problem is stated is a little confusing. Two strings in the diagram are marked $0$. Those strings have fixed length. It would have been clearer to say the lengths are $l_1$ and $l_2$. But $0$ works. That would attach the top of the left pully to the ceiling and m$_3$ to the center of the right pulley.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question not a "do my homework" question.

Comment: @mmesser314 I am a bit new here so I dont know how to add images in the comments.. so I edited the question to add another pic.
So, the second set of string, l2, I understood, that y length is assumed... but I dont get the y + x and -2 -x... i understand that mathematically adding these parts give 0, which is what the procedure wants us to do... but they seem a bit too arbitrary to me. Like, what i I replaced y + x with y -x and then replaced 2y -x with 2y + x?

Comment: I think the length 0 is taken because the purpose is to find constraint relations between masses' velocity and acceleration. So they took the "constants" to be zero. ( $v= dx/dt$ and $a=dv/dt$), which would anyway become zero...

Comment: It looks like coordinates are even more messed up than I thought. You are right. They are taking the lengths of the yellow and green strings to be 0. They plainly aren't, but they are of constant length. The problem is saying that the two sides must add to 0, meaning one end must be at x and the other at -x.  This makes no sense. A coordinate 0f -x would be above the ceiling. A string from -x to x does not have a length of 0.

Comment: A better way to think of what the problem says is that each mass and each pulley has its own coordinates, where the + directly is down. Each starts at position 0. Because the length of the yellow string is constant, if m$_1$ moves down to position x, the left pulley moves up to position -x.

Comment: If m$_1$ moves down to x and m$_3$ moves down to y, the the right pulley moves to y. Also you can show that m$_2$ moves up to -x-2y. From that, you can solve the problem.